# phpMyAdmin and mysql reserved words

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In phpMyAdmin I can set a column name using mysql reserved words.
For example - `cache`.
There is no any alert, any info, but it can produce problems later.

Usually I'm going [**here**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-B), scroll down, click on a letter and scroll again to check if a word is reserved or not.

Is there a way just to type a word somewhere and get that info?

Or set pma to not accept this column, table names etc.

Comment: In the early 2000's I managed to name a column "*" (don't question it), and everytime I wrote "SELECT * FROM table" it would return only that one. I tried it a few years ago, but (at least phpmyadmin) didn't let me do it.

Comment: Btw, why don't you just use search on this page? Ctrl+F in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: @kry btw because it's not a funny way in 2018

Comment: Don't use phpmyadmin then. :D You can refer to individual columns with 'column_name', and it won't mix it up with reserved words. Not the most elegant way, but if you not changing to a different UI, you have to let it roll over you.

Comment: @kry could you recommend me some alternatives, pls?

Comment: https://www.adminer.org/en/phpmyadmin/ I found it after a bit Google search. However probably does not include what you want, since by definition it is allowed to give columns names that are reserved keywords. In the mind of the MySQL developers, users refer to column names as strings, and phpmyadmin devs didn't feel like adding a restriction either.

Comment: do I understand you well? do you say that `cache` is reserved but`'cache'` - is not?

Comment: Aye. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html "An identifier may be quoted or unquoted. If an identifier contains special characters or is a reserved word, you must quote it whenever you refer to it. (Exception: A reserved word that follows a period in a qualified name must be an identifier, so it need not be quoted.) Reserved words are listed at Section 9.3, “Keywords and Reserved Words”." You just have to tell the MySQL, it's not a command, but just a word. It's kinda like using the dot selector, when getting info from multiple tables. table1.column_name and table2.column_nam

Comment: e. You need to be exact, in your case, the MySQL might misunderstand you, so you have to make it clear, you are thinking about the column name, and not the keyword.

Comment: @kry clear enough, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you hadn't found it yet, the MySQL dev website has a list of reserved words: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: My bad :) Sorry! You could press ctrl+f and type a word there to do a quicker search.